# Assign a vector to two category based on another vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors one is continues and one is categorised.

First of all, I could not generate a categorised vector so I just generated (tt) the same way as `t`.

I want to write a function which take the median of the vector `t`
then check for each value of the vector `t` `if it is >= median` , assign the `tt` to `low` otherwise to `high` and somehow plot the results.

So far I did as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
t<- rnorm(100)
tt<- rnorm(100)
# calculate the median of t 
mer<- median(t)
if If mer(i) <= median
tt assigned to low
if mer(i) > median
tt assigned to high
```

Then I want to plot the results.

Comment: Perhaps `ifelse(tt>mer, 'high', 'low')` or `c('low', 'high')[(tt>mer)+1L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by acrun and nico, you could use `ifelse`:

```
hl = ifelse(tt>mer, 'high', 'low')
```

and then to plot:

```
plot(t, tt, col=ifelse(hl=="high", "red", "blue"))
legend("topright", legend=c("high", "low"), fill=c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is easily obtained by using `ifelse`

```
set.seed(123)
t <- rnorm(100)
# Calculate the median of t 
med <- median(t)

tt <- ifelse(t > med, "HIGH", "LOW")
```

`ifelse` works on vectors, so the last call is equivalent of doing a `for` cycle and checking each element of `t`.

In certain situations it may also be useful to convert `tt` to a factor

```
tt <- factor(tt, levels=c("LOW", "HIGH"))
```